# How can I update image source in a Bootstrap 5 modal based on the trigger element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap5-modal

I made an image gallery. And when I click an image, a large image is shown in modal.

If there are 5 images and when you click 5th image, I would like to scroll down to the 5th large image directly in the modal. Is it possible to make it?

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a href="#First" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1st image</a>
<a href="#Second" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">2nd image</a>
<a href="#Third" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">3rd image</a>
<a href="#Fourth" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">4th image</a>
<a href="#Fifth" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">5th image</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="item" id="First"><img src="/first.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item" id="Second"><img src="/second.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item" id="Third"><img src="/third.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item" id="Fourth"><img src="/fourth.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item" id="Fifth"><img src="/fifth.jpg" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/jandspace/pen/xxPmVem

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's often best to react to Bootstrap's [modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#events). Here I've converted your triggers to image elements. (Anchors really shouldn't be used for actions anyway.) Then we can just get the image source from the trigger image using `relatedTarget`. Should you need to use anchors a slight adjustment would be needed, but the same concept applies.

Also, we can dramatically simplify your markup by not repeating the elements inside the modal.

Note that I've added the `img-fluid` class to the modal image to keep it from blowing out the side.

```js
// this could be placed in a script element at the end of the body element

const exampleModalEl = document.getElementById('exampleModal');

exampleModalEl.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  document.getElementById('modalImage').src = event.relatedTarget.src;
});
```

```css
.thumb {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class="thumb" />

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800/ff0000" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class="thumb" />

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800/0000ff" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class="thumb" />

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="item"><img id="modalImage" class="img-fluid" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With some slight changes to your code, you can add click handlers to each of the buttons that change the `src` attribute of the image inside the modal:

```js
['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'].forEach(function(key) {
  $('a[href="#' + key + '"]').click(
    function() {
      $('#image').attr('src', '/' + key + '.jpg');
    }
  )
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a href="#first" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">1st image</a>
<a href="#second" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">2nd image</a>
<a href="#third" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">3rd image</a>
<a href="#fourth" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">4th image</a>
<a href="#fifth" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">5th image</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="item"><img id="image" src="" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, but you shouldn't be introducing jQuery. Bootstrap doesn't depend on it and it adds load weight. I realize that it's in the CodePen demo, but it isn't needed here. `each` loops and event handlers are trivial with raw JavaScript.

Comment: @isherwood The original question was tagged with jQuery so I assumed it was fair game because it was already being loaded.

Comment: Fair enough. I missed the tag. My greater point stands, though.